# How to get child terms based on parent terms between two different taxonomies

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I have created two vocabulary

1. Program
2. Topics

I want to load the topics based on the program selection.

It looks like category and subcategory.

I created some program like java, .net, PHP 
and I created some topics like session (php), inheritance(java), cookie(php).

So now I want to list all the topics which are coming under a particular program.

Can you tell me which  drupal function used to get all the terms under parent terms.?

Note: `taxonomy_get_children` not working because I am using two vocabularies

Comment: You've not defined how your 2 taxonomies have a relationship. If you've not done this, you need to find out how to do that. See http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/96280/hierarchy-between-terms-from-different-vocabularies-in-drupal-7.

Comment: Hi ..I mentioned its look like category and subcategory.so topics contain program term id as parent.

Comment: Without explaining how the relationship is defined (e.g. term reference field within your taxonomy entities), no one can give you an answer to question.

Comment: ya i used term reference in topics.it point to the program vocabulary

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to load your content's term references and then load those term entities so you can follow your chain of taxonomy terms. There's many ways to do that; [`taxonomy_term_load_multiple()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_term_load_multiple/7.x) is one such function.

```
$tids = array();

// @TODO: Use the $nid that corresponds with your node 
// @TODO: Replace field_program & field_topic with your taxonomy ref field name
$node = node_load($nid);
foreach ($node->field_programs[LANGUAGE_NONE] as $term) {
  $tids[] = $term['tid'];
}
$programs = taxonomy_term_load_multiple($tids);

// @TODO: Iterate over $programs and retrieve 
// topic tid references from $program->field_topic[LANGUAGE_NONE]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add code in template.php as theme_preprocess_page() 

`if(arg(0) == 'taxonomy' && arg(1) == 'term') 
  {
        $tid = (int)arg(2);
        $term = taxonomy_term_load($tid);
        $arrTermId = taxonomy_get_children($tid);
        $arrData = taxonomy_select_nodes(array_keys($arrTermId), $pager = TRUE, $limit = FALSE, $order = array('t.sticky' => 'DESC', 't.created' => 'DESC'));
        $arrContent = node_load_multiple($arrData, $conditions = array(), $reset = FALSE);
print_r($arrContent);
  }`

In $arrContent you will get values of all the nodes.